# How to capture globe-shaped photograph?

Tags: wide-angle, fisheye

I am a beginner photographer. How to capture this kind of photograph. Any technique?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

For an image like that, a "fisheye" lens was used.  This is a specialized lens that covers an extreme wide angle.

[What can a fisheye lens be useful for?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/what-can-a-fisheye-lens-be-useful-for/1803#1803)

Comment: Probably an idea to mark this question as 'answered' if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need an expensive fisheye lens to produce this effect.
The linked image is a series of multiple shots and stitched in Photoshop
http://www.panoramio.com/photo/41726629?tag=best

You can see more images like this at
http://www.panoramio.com/user/221285

Answer (score 1):

As MikeW said, it is a fisheye lens.  A fisheye lens is generally recognizable from it's characteristic dome shape.  It bends the light far more than a typical flat lens and is therefore able to capture an exceptionally wide field of view, but since it is semi-circular, it ends up distorting the edges of the image with the characteristic curvature that you see.

Answer (score 1):

A **fisheye lens** was used. It is often used for a **comical effect**, but they can be **very expensive**, especially for a beginner.

You can add **fisheye effects** to the image for free, producing similar results. Try this out at [LunaPic](http://www.lunapic.com/?fisheye) (I don't know if they still do this) or you could follow this [Photoshop Tutorial](http://www.digiretus.com/tippek/cikkiro.php?SORSZAM=190).

Comment: trying to do this without a fisheye would require a very wide rectilinear lens (even more expensive) or shooting a multi row panorama. It probably easier to just scour eBay for one of the cheap third party fisheyes.